# ALGORITHM PARTITION QS

Tags: c, quicksort

[image: Algoritmo MUlti-Pivot]

Podrían orientarme el como funciona este algoritmo

Comment: Sé cómo funciona este medio de ordenamiento, pero en `scheme` o `dr racket`. No sé si será la misma lógica que en pseudocódigo.

Comment: @JuanCamiloPerezRodriguez ¿Podrías agregar una respuesta explicando ese algoritmo?

Comment: También tu podrías editar la pregunta y sustituir la imagen por texto. Si el enlace a la imagen se pierde tu pregunta solo servirá para tirarla a la basura

Answer (score 2):

El pseudocódigo no está hecho para un lenguaje o para otro, sino que trata de abstraerse de los mismos para ser  comprensible por todos los programadores aún cuando no todos programamos en el mismo lenguaje.

Explicarte el pseudocódigo por completo no tendría mucho sentido. Si bien es cierto que los hay que introducen más detalles que otros.

Creo que es un esfuerzo mental que debes realizar y, si no eres capaz, empezar por algoritmos más sencillos.

Te dejo un gif que te ayudará  a elaborar una imagen mental del proceder del algoritmo y después estar en condiciones de entender mucho mejor el pseudocódigo.

Si después tienes dudas más concretas,  como alguno de los bucles,  por supuesto se te puede ayudar.

[simulación del algoritmo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Sorting_quicksort_anim.gif)

Edito:

Yo he tenido que preparar asignaturas de algoritmia en la ingeniería y siempre me ha sido de mucha ayuda coger un folio, un lápiz y comenzar a ejecutar el algoritmo manualmente. Primero con casos sencillos y poco a  poco aumentando la complejidad. Aún hoy en día soy de coger papel y folio para hacerme la imagen mental en casos concretos.  Mucha gente tiene la gran capacidad de hacer esto de forma automática mentalmente.  Con la práctica  podrás.
Espero te sirva.